# Integer partition identity

Tags: combinatorics

Let be $ p(n,4)$  number of partitions of $ n $ in parts no greater than $4$ then

$$p(13n,4)-p(n,4)={61\over4}n^3 + {35\over2}n^2  + \frac{45+3(-1)^n}{8}n$$

I can prove this identity that seems to me very interesting (In my work, still unpublished, I need 3 or 4 pages to explain it at all). If someone has any reference where is mentioned above formula lets me know, or a short proof if it is possible. See [A191698] in OEIS

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For fixed $k$, the sequence $p(n, k)$ has [generating function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function)

$$F_k(x) = \sum_{n \ge 0} p(n, k) x^n = \frac{1}{(1 - x)(1 - x^2)...(1 - x^k)}.$$

This generating function is rational, so partial fraction decomposition gives an explicit formula for its coefficients. If this isn't covered in Wilf's [generatingfunctionology](http://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/DownldGF.html), it should be covered in Flajolet and Sedgewick's [Analytic Combinatorics](http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/books.html).

A very general approach to automatically proving certain types of combinatorial identities, which I am reasonably sure handles this special case correctly, is described in Petkovsek, Wilf, and Zeilberger's [A=B](http://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/AeqB.html).

Comment: I have checked all books as you suggested in none of them there was not any comment about my identity. you

Comment: I wouldn't expect there to be. My point is that those books should cover general methods for proving identities that include this one as a special case.

Comment: Can you explain how to go further from generating function and explicitly get this identity. I am trying but without any results.

Comment: @Adi: the details are messy, but completely algorithmic. Perhaps you should try $k = 2$ first: the partial fraction decomposition is much easier to deal with in that case. Are you familiar with how to do partial fraction decompositions when the denominator has repeated roots?

Comment: Qiaochu: If we go that way starting at k=2  we need to proceed with case k=3 then k=4 That is the way I get formula and for that purpose I needed 4 pages. I want to know if there exists any shorter path. According to your answer the only way to get this identity is the way I have already got.

Comment: @Adi: I only suggested $k = 2$ as an exercise, not as a necessary step in proving this identity. Again, the details are messy, but algorithmic. There are probably computer algebra packages (perhaps they are described in A=B) that can automatically do this for you.

Answer (score 3):

With regard to Qiaochu's answer, the partial fraction decomposition is messy (compared, say, to anything you'd put on a calculus exam), having 8 terms, and coefficients like 59/288. It's worked out in detail in the lovely book by Andrews and Eriksson, Integer Partitions, in Section 6.3, A formula for $p(n,4)$, pages 58-60. They give several formulas for $p(n,4)$, perhaps the simplest is $$p(n,4)={\rm\ nearest\ integer\ to\ }{(n+5)(n^2+n+22+18\left[{n\over2}\right])\over144}$$

I suppose one could use this to have a go at $q(n)=p(13n,4)-p(n,4)$. But it might be better to work directly with a generating function for $q(n)$.

Answer (score 1):

To add to Qiaochu's answer, there is a large body of work in existence on the [Partition Function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartitionFunctionP.html).  Let $P(n,k)$ denote the number of ways to write $n$ as a sum of *exactly* $k$ positive integers.  (Similar to your $p(n,k)$ above)  Then we have the recurrence relation $$P(n,k)=P(n-1,k-1)+P(n-k,k).$$  This can be solved exactly, see equations $(61)$ to $(66)$ of the Wolfram link.